# Duration of /proc/pid/stat

Tags: linux, process, proc, exit

I have a process that starts a child process and when the child exits, scans `/proc/<pid>/stat` to gather some information about the CPU and memory the child used. However I am worried that I am living on borrowed time here. How long after `wait()` returns or `SIGCHLD` is sent/signal handler is called, will it actually hang around? It would be super convenient if they lasted until the PID needed to be reused but that's clearly not what's happening.

Comment: If you are using C, see also `getrusage(2)` and `times(2)`.

Comment: `pid` values are not re-used.  The count will be incremented with each new process.  The only 'reasonable' method of resetting the count is to re-boot the computer.

Comment: @user3629249 That's completely wrong. PID values *are* reused.

Comment: `/proc/<pid>/stat` no longer exists by the time `wait` returns. You mention a short delay during which it still exists, but that doesn't jibe with my reading of the code, nor with my understanding of the architecture (the data is supposed to be reclaimed when the parent calls `wait`), and I cannot reproduce this on Debian jessie. What kernel version are you using? Are you absolutely sure about the timing and that you're hitting the right child? In any case, it's clearly not something you can count on.

Comment: @Gilles,  My experience, with linux and unix, is that `pid`s are not reused.  Otherwise there would be little to no gaps in the PID values and a long running computer would not have huge PID values

Comment: @user3629249 Once again, no. Try it on Linux, for example: if you leave it running for long enough, eventually the PIDs reach 32767, which is the maximum value, and then they start again at the first free PID. If PIDs were never reused, that would mean that the system would lock up after a certain number of forks! How long you have before a PID is reused depends on how long the process survived: if it survived for about 32700 forks, the PID could be the next one to be reused.

Answer (score 2):

`/proc/[pid]` disappears when the program exits. See this: https://superuser.com/questions/365576/lifetime-of-the-symlinks-from-the-file-descriptors-in-proc-pid-fd

**edit:**

The wait man page says

> The wait() function shall suspend execution of the calling thread until
>   status information for one of the terminated  child  processes  of  the
>   calling  process  is  available,  or  until  delivery of a signal whose
>   action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to  terminate
>   the  process.

So it is possible that a signal to terminate the child process is delivered. Then `wait` returned, but the child process has not yet exited. So you can still read `/proc/pid/stat`. When the child process exits, `/proc/pid/stat` disappears.

Comment: It doesn't tho', or at least, it's not as simple as that. My `wait()` has returned and I have received `SIGCHLD` but my child process's entry in `/proc` is *still there* long enough for me to take a quick peek.

Comment: the code gets the childs PID when the call to `fork()` is made to create the child process.  Suggest examining the /proc pid sub directory while the child is still running

Comment: How would `wait` return before the child process has exited?